# marklogic build simple document using element and attribute functions

Tags: attributes, element, xquery, marklogic

OK really simple but I cannot seem to find documentation to get this done...

I want to build the following docuemnt:

```
<category name="oplages">
<variable name="oplage_aggegated">
<segment name="bruto">2892</segment>
<segment name="stickers">451</segment>
<segment name="netto">2441</segment>
</variable>
</category>
```

I used "element" before but I need to add attributes now...

This works:

```
  let $ns := "http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk"
  let $wijk-bruto := 5
  let $wijk-stick := 2
  let $wijk-netto := 3

  return <wijk id="test" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk">{
    element meta-data { comment {"Generated by DIKW for NetwerkVSP STT!P "},
    element dateCreated {fn:current-date()}}, 
       element category  {
         element bruto {$wijk-bruto},
         element stickers {$wijk-stick},
         element netto {$wijk-netto}
    }}
    </wijk>
```

Gives:

```
<wijk id="test" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk">
<meta-data>
<!--
Generated by DIKW for NetwerkVSP STT!P
-->
<dateCreated>2014-06-06+02:00</dateCreated>
</meta-data>
<category>
<bruto>5</bruto>
<stickers>2</stickers>
<netto>3</netto>
</category>
</wijk>
```

Now how can I add attributes here?

I feel stupid

tx

hugo

Comment: searching google gives me a headache as element and attribute are so common words...

Comment: A tip for searching: `element name { "value" }` and `attribute name { "value" }` are called element/attribute constructors.

Comment: More specifically these are "computed constructors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
let $ns := "http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk"
let $wijk-bruto := 5
let $wijk-stick := 2
let $wijk-netto := 3

return 
<wijk id="test" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk">
 {element category  
  {attribute 
   {'Netto' } { $wijk-netto }
  }    
 }
</wijk>
```

To create the specific document I would use this:

```
let $ns := "http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk"
let $wijk-bruto := 5
let $wijk-stick := 2
let $wijk-netto := 3

return 
<wijk id="test" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk">
<category name="oplages">
<variable name="oplage_aggegated">
  <segment> 
    {attribute { 'name' } { 'bruto' }} {$wijk-bruto}
  </segment>

  <segment> 
    {attribute { 'name' } { 'netto' }} {$wijk-netto}
  </segment>

  <segment>
    {attribute { 'name' } { 'stick' }} {$wijk-stick}
  </segment>
</variable>
</category>
</wijk>
```

Comment: `attribute name { 'fubar' }` also works. Note that any attribute nodes must come before any non-attribute nodes.

Comment: You can also use `fn:QName` and `xs:Qname` to dynamically provide namespaces elem/attr names: `element { fn:QName($ns, 'segment') } { ... }`..